# Post request from JQuery to CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I am creating a web application that uses CakePHP as the back end and JQuery as the front end. In order to communicate with the server, I wanted to make GET and Post requests from JQuery using ajax. Here is what I have right now:

```
function submit_registration(fname, lname, email, pass)
{
  var arr = { data: {User: { fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, password: pass }}};

  $.post('http://localhost/cake2/users/add', JSON.stringify(arr), function(response){
  alert(response);
  })
}
```

That is in JQuery. Here is the add action in CakePHP:

```
public function add()
{   
    $this->layout = null ;

    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
        $this->User->create();

        if ($this->User->save($data))
        {
            $this->set('data', "success");
            $this->render('/General/JsonMode2/');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->set('data', "failure to save");
            $this->render('/General/JsonMode2/');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set('data', "failure to post");
        $this->render('/General/JsonMode2/');
    }
}
```

It renders as JSON back to the front end. My problem is, nothing happens when I submit the request. I put alerts to ensure that the submit_registration function was being called. Can anyone give me a clue as the what is going on?

Comment: I know this is not the question, but you shouldn't _post_ a password through http

Comment: This is just for testing

Comment: can you output error on $.post like : `error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){alert(errorThrown );}`

Comment: You can’t build a whole front-end in jQuery.

Comment: @Leonardo how else is a password to be submitted?

Comment: Why is jQuery needed for a post request? If a form is present (or constructed with with `$this->Form->start()/input()/end()`) the logic and redirecting/rendering of pages could be handled solely by php, a better approach imho.

Comment: You'd just use `$this->redirect('/General/JsonMode2/');` instead of `$this->render('/General/JsonMode2/');`

Comment: @AD7six using HTTPS or at least encrypt it in the client-side

Comment: @Leonardo Using https is of course a good idea but suggesting that the whole web is https is simply impractical/unrealistic. Encrypting client side doesn't add any security - the encryption algorithm and salt/parameters could simply be extracted from the js making it added complexity for no real benefit.

Comment: @Sam the front end and back end are not working together. Cake is not rendering html views. It should be sending data back to the client, which could be a mobile app or anything else.

Comment: @Gregory-Turtle I believe what you mean is that the frontend is _disassociated_ from the backend; it's clearer to simply describe the cakephp application as api-only, even though the code in the question contradicts that. Incidentally you may find this interesting [Crud plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud) - which would provide you an instant robust api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the script function to this:

```
function submit_registration(fname, lname, email, pass)
{
  var data = {User: { fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, password: pass }};

  $.post('http://localhost/cake2/users/add', data, function(response){
  alert(response);
  })
}
```

and change $data = $this->request->input('json_decode'); to

```
$data = $this->data;
```

To debug the response, use CakeResponse like this:

```
return new CakeResponse(array('body'=> json_encode('...message here...'),'status'=>200));
```

Comment: +1 It would be a good idea to also correct having the domain name in the post call. Most likely this should be a variable that is prepended to all api urls used in the app e.g. `var api = 'http://localhost/cake2'; ... $.post(api . '/users/add',...`. If it's the same domain it doesn't need to be a url, it could be just the relative path.